# Converting Existing Dnn Application to .Net core

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, dotnetnuke, asp.net-apicontroller

Converting Existing Dnn Application to .Net core

I have a application of dnn having ado which I need to convert to .net core with ado web application.
In this I have to move only two modules from the application.
what i have already tried so far.
cleaned the database from the dnn tables.
changed the ascx pages to partial views.
changing the ascx.cs pages to the controller.

Need Recommendations for fast conversion and if I can follow any pattern.

Comment: Good luck, modules are designed to work with the DNN core systems. You cannot just "convert" them. The best option is to create them from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

Given the nature of the way that the DNN Platform works, there is not a fast transition to a stand-alone installation.

There is no Microsoft documented "Fast" transition plan from Web-Forms to .NET Core as well, so nothing that you can try to mimic from other installations either.

Since you will need to extract dependencies on DNN as well as dependencies on System.Web that are no longer available, it is best to treat such a transition as a re-write, rather than trying to "simply translate" as there isn't any method to do so.

Comment: With .NET 6, WebForms work again, right? Should that make it possible to move DNN to .NET 6 with "appropriate" effort? That would make it possible to containerize DNN - a huge plus for the platform.

Comment: I saw your comment in the DNN community forum - missing support for System.Web, that pretty much explains why it would be quiet the endeavor to port to .NET 6.

Comment: @TvdH yes, that's pretty much the rub.  No System.Web = No easy path.  We "could" do it, but it would break almost everything that was ever written.

Comment: Will https://github.com/dotnet/systemweb-adapters be helpful?